# How to set application context path in angular2 routing properly?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have created an Angular project using angular-cli (version : 1.0.0-beta.28.3). I run the application in development environment using "npm start" and the application runs fine in "localhost:4200". Now to replicate production deployment, I wanted to run the application in local WAMP. So, I ran 'ng build -prod', copied the files from 'dist' folder to WAMP's www/student directory. Now when I run the project through WAMP, I end up getting this error :

[image]

Obviously, the application was looking for the required js files in the wrong location. I did some research, and found that the context root - in my case 'student' had to be set in "base href="/student" inside the index.html. Due to angular-cli's bug, each time I typed 'ng build -prod', the base href got reset to "/". Found a workaround; typing "ng build -prod --base-href student" set the base href to student.

Now I ran into a new problem. The default page was supposed to show the contents of route 'app-home', but launching the app gives me :

[image]

But, both of the routes/ links are working fine. For example clicking 'About Us' changes the url to 'http://localhost:82/student/student/app-about-us' and shows appropriate content.

I am quite sure I have a problem with my routing. Please help me set the routing in a way so that I can get the application running in 'http://localhost:82/student' with sub-urls 
'http://localhost:82/student/student/app-home' (default) and 'http://localhost:82/student/student/app-about-us'

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { CarComponent } from './car/car.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { CONST_ROUTING } from "app/app.routing";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    CarComponent,
    MenuComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CONST_ROUTING

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from "app/home/home.component";
import { AboutUsComponent } from "app/about-us/about-us.component";

const MAINMENU_ROUTES: Routes = [
 //full : makes sure the path is absolute path
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/app-home', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'app-home', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'app-about-us', component: AboutUsComponent }
];
export const CONST_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(MAINMENU_ROUTES);
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['/app-home']" >Home</a></li>
 <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['/app-about-us']" >About Us</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <app-menu></app-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ang2RouterTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to set the `--base-href` to the web url, ie `http://www.mytestpage.com/`, you must include the trailing slash

Comment: if its a node hosted app, the base href can be `/` if the node server handles the request correctly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this option to create build

```
ng build --base-href .
```

base href works everywhere.

See Example where i hosted on xampp :
[image]

Comment: that would work but the QA needs to set the base href to a web url, not just`.`

Comment: maybe so but it needs to be set to his web url that the app will be hosted on for it to work properly

Comment: never did for me, an absolute path needs to be set unless hosted via a node server in which case, `/` works fine

Comment: always worked for me, even used it to host cordova apps. u must be having some diff issue

Comment: no issue, it should only work in the 2 circumstances i mentioned above

Comment: Worked for me ! Launching the app redirects me to 'http://localhost:82/student/app-home' and it works fine. Is there any risk involving this strategy?

Comment: Nope.. PathLocation has advantages over HashLocation like SEO Friendliness & Static Resource caching

Comment: @TahniatAshraf : see edit, base href . will work everywhere. you can accept as answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. @ParthGhiya Your solution was the first one I tried, and it worked for me :)

Comment: however, notice the url has `dist`? thats why you should use what i recommended

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : because i have kept dist content inside xampp, if i dont keep any folder then `http://localhost/login` will also work for me ....

Comment: Good solution . This option should be the default (and included in angular.json). One of the few workaround needed to make a project work.

Comment: 5 years later with Angular 12 and this solution worked for me lol. I was deploying my app with spring-boot with a custom servlet.context-path and this helped me fix my app-root not getting filled in

Comment: hahaha @takanuva15 !!

Answer (score 4):

Standard host - `ng build --base-href http://www.yourwebsitehere.com/`. Make sure to remember the trailing slash

NodeJS host - `ng build`. Make sure to setup your NodeJS server properly though

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the context path of your application. Create a service which gets the application context of your application and append this context path to your route paths this would solve the issue i guess.

Comment: this is a more appropriate approach. Creating environment specific builds is not a good idea. IMO it is silly to include an argument like base-ref to ng build

Answer (score 0):

Other option appart from adding the the parameter in the build:
You can add the base href in your index.html

```html
<head>
  ...
  <base href=".">
  ...
</head>
```