# Angular SPA anywhere on the site without recompiling the SPA

Tags: angular, routes

I've created a simple photo gallery showing pictures in a  timeline.  The development env is Angular ( v14 ) using angular routing.  I'd like to have the flexibility of placing the gallery anywhere on the site and just referencing it with a link on the site's main page.

I have been experimenting with routes and think the following should work but it does not and just gives a blank page:

{ path: '', children: [{ path: '**', component: GalleryViewComponent}]}

I'd like to install the SPA on the server:

./mysite/galleries/angSPA

so that I can access it with the URL:

https://mysite/galleries/angSPA

I'm missing something with routing or angular routing so would appreciate any thoughts/comments.

Comment: You need to configure context path for your application in the server and in the angular application index.html the bhref tag is set to "./"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sreemat for pointing me in the right direction.

Looking in this direction, I find that Angular 2, for version 11 anyway, sets up the new application environment so that the context base is "/".  So if your site is https://mysite, then the files generated for your angular app must be located in ./mysite/ on the server.  If you put them in ./mysite/special and expect the URL to be https://mysite/special, the app will not work without modification.

A simple solution is given in stackoverflow answer to question [43845741](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845741/how-to-set-application-context-path-in-angular2-routing-properly).

```
ng build --base-href .
```

My complete build command is :

```
ng build -c production --base-href ./ --aot --output-hashing=all
```

This did fix my problem.

Note that another answer by @raj240 suggest that it is a better idea to programmatically get the context base and add it to the routes in the route table.  I will look at this approach too.

Comment: Great! Good work